# How to write orientation data with exifinterface directly to image buffer (or rotate the image itself)?

Tags: android, image, kotlin

I'm taking images using the `Camera2 API`.

As far as I understand, if the device is rotated during image capturing, you can set the corresponding rotation to the jpg file using the exifinterface.
However, I do not store the image to a file, but rather send the image buffer - which I receive from the capture request - directly to a remote client via LAN:

```
// function within my camera manager class to take the image. 
// at this point the camera session is already set up and running
fun takePhotoJPEG(cmdDispatcher: CommandDispatcher) {

    val jpegImageList = ArrayList<Image>()

    jpegImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
        jpegImageList.add(reader.acquireLatestImage())
    }, null)


    val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).apply {
        addTarget(jpegImageReader.surface)
    }
    setSingleCaptureRequestSettings(captureRequest)

    session.captureSingleRequest(captureRequest.build(), cameraExecutor, object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureStarted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, timestamp: Long, frameNumber: Long) {
            super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber)
            logger.log("Capturing JPEG image...")
        }

        override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)

            var cnt = 0
            while (jpegImageList.size < 1) {
                runBlocking {
                    delay(10)
                }
                if (cnt++ > 100) break
            }

            if (jpegImageList.size > 0) {


                val jpegbuffer = jpegImageList.first().planes[0].buffer //I want to either rotate this image, or add exif header with the orientation information
                val bytes = ByteArray(jpegbuffer.remaining())

                jpegbuffer.get(bytes, 0, jpegbuffer.remaining())
                logger.log("JPEG Image Captured. Sending to client...")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cmdDispatcher.sendImageToClient(bytes, NetworkCommandTypeEnum.IMAGEJPEG)
                }
                jpegImageList.first().close()
            } else {
                logger.log("JPEG Image Capture failed...")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    cmdDispatcher.sendFailedCommand()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Question now is:

- Can I add an exif header to the byte buffer directly?
- Alternatively, is there a relatively fast way to get the correctly rotated image in the first place?
- I have the same function as above for RAW images, but as far as I can tell, since I'm using `DngCreator` there, I can set the orientation using that for raw images.

Comment: `I do not have a file, but rather send the image buffer` How did you obtain that buffer and what does it contain? You wrote a pretty unreadable post as i have no idea what you are doing Please rewrite your post and start with the beginning.

Comment: @blackapps I rewrote some of the OP and included the complete method to capture the image. Hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: If there is a jpg file in the byte buffer then i would expect it has already an exif header. And with the right orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing around a bunch I found the following answer to my question.

**For JPEG images:**

Use the `CaptureRequest` directly and set the value for the tag [`JPEG_ORIENTATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#JPEG_ORIENTATION) according to the devices orientation.
I simply used the display rotation, since only values of 0, 90, 180, 270 are allowed anyway:

```
val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).apply {
    addTarget(jpegImageReader.surface)
}
val displayManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
when(displayManager.displays[0].rotation) {
    Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
        captureRequest.set(JPEG_ORIENTATION, 90)
        logger.log("orientation: NORMAL")
    }
    Surface.ROTATION_90 -> {
        captureRequest.set(JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0)
        logger.log("orientation: 90")
    }
    Surface.ROTATION_180 -> {
        captureRequest.set(JPEG_ORIENTATION, 270)
        logger.log("orientation: 180")
    }
    Surface.ROTATION_270 -> {
        captureRequest.set(JPEG_ORIENTATION, 180)
        logger.log("orientation: 270")
    }
}
```

One might notice, that the values set are different from the display rotation. This is because the camera sensor itself also has a orientation value, which in this example I omitted and simply used hardcoded values. If one wants to take the sensor orientation into account, this can easily be queried using CameraCharacteristics and the tag [`SENSOR_ORIENTATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SENSOR_ORIENTATION).

**For RAW images:**

Here, I captured the image first and then used [`DngCreator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/DngCreator) to write the image stream and also set the orientation:

```
val dngCreator = DngCreator(characteristics, result)
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val displayManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
when(displayManager.displays[0].rotation){
    Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
        dngCreator.setOrientation(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
        logger.log("orientation: NORMAL")
    }
    Surface.ROTATION_90 -> {
        dngCreator.setOrientation(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
        logger.log("orientation: 90")
    }
    Surface.ROTATION_180 -> {
        dngCreator.setOrientation(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
        logger.log("orientation: 180")
    }
    Surface.ROTATION_270 -> {
        dngCreator.setOrientation(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
        logger.log("orientation: 270")
    }
}
dngCreator.writeImage(stream, rawImageList.first())
```

Each of those methods are used in my application to send the image data to a desktop application, where I store them as files on a Windows machine. With those methods, when opening the images, they are always rotated correctly.

Comment: That's the right path for setting them, but do keep in mind that for most apps, hardcoding the display->rotation values doesn't work well. Most cases you want keep images upright relative to gravity, so you want to look at the accelerometer output as well as the orientation of the display and sensor, to calculate the orientation value for the JPEG.

Comment: @EddyTalvala absolutely, however in my case it is for an project at University, not a production app. So for me it doesn't matter so much, but it's good to have this comment added to the answer!